# How to execute multiple tests classes in gradle that are not in the same package?

Tags: unit-testing, gradle

I have the following tests classes.

1. com.baz.bar.Foo
2. com.bar.foo.Baz
3. com.foo.baz.Bar

I want to execute `com.baz.bar.Foo` and `com.bar.foo.Baz`. I know how to execute all of them and how to execute one of them. I don't know how to execute any arbitrary set between.

Comment: Do you want to specify the classes as command line arguments, or in the build script?

Comment: Ideally it is at the command line.

Answer (score 49):

Gradle supports multiple `--tests` statements, i.e:

```
gradle test --tests com.baz.bar.Foo --tests com.bar.foo.Baz --tests com.foo.baz.Bar
```

would do what you want

Comment: Does not work for me with a "Multiple arguments were provided for command-line option '--tests'" message

Comment: Does the base case work for you?
"gradle test"
executes all tests?
"gradle test --tests a"
"gradle test --tests b"
execute test a and b respectively?

Which OS? Which shell?
This works for me us on different Windows systems on Windows cmd and cygwin.
(With powershell you have to add quotes and brackets and stuff IIRC)

Comment: Base cases work for me. `gradle test --tests a` works, `gradle test --tests b` works. I'm on Ubuntu with bash

Comment: Huh, I would try putting brackets or quotes around the two --tests statements... maybe try a more fancy terminal?

Answer (score 8):

It's easy to do in a build script:

```
test {
    filter {
        filterTestsMatching "com.baz.bar.Foo", "com.bar.foo.Baz", ...
    }
}
```

The command line equivalent is `gradle test --tests com.baz.bar.Foo` (or just `--tests Foo`), but from what I can tell, only a single class (more precisely a single pattern) is supported here.

If you need the ability to pass multiple patterns, you can script this yourself. For example, you could read a system property passed from the command line via `-Dtest.filter=Foo,Bar,Baz`, split the value into its individual parts, and feed those into `filterTestsMatching`.

Enhancing `--tests` to support comma-delimited values might make a good pull request for the Gradle project.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is an extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40900995/2987755)

Command line option:
If you want to execute multiple tests which are in different packages from command line, you can execute as follows:
<> --> replace with values

```bash
format: [gradle or ./gradlew] <Task name> --tests "<package-name>.<* or class-name>"

gradle test --tests "com.xyz.*" --tests "org.abc.*"
# OR with gradle wrapper
./gradlew test --tests "com.xyz.*" --tests "org.abc.*"
```

Above command will execute all tests present in package `com.xyz` and `org.abc` for `test` task, same command can be used for other functional and integration tasks as well.

Verified with gradle version 7.4 for java/kotlin project.

[Reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#full_qualified_name_pattern)